# What's the configuration for unhandled compile time exception in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse :What is the configuration required for unhandled compile time exception in Eclipse?

Comment: This is very unclear. What do you mean by 'unhandled compile time exception'?

Comment: i am using pInputJson.getString("abc") and not handling jsonException in my code since getString() method throws jsonException but compiler is not pointing out the exception and code is complied sucessfully.

Comment: If the exception is a `RuntimeException` then the compiler will not insist that you deal with it and there is no configuration to change this.

Comment: @AkasnhaGoyal That looks more to me like a Runtime exception, and you would have to work around it within your code.

Comment: For the same line of code [pInputJson.getString("abc") ] compiler is pointing out the error in some other machine. but its not in mine.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you mean:

> Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings

From there, you can set each of the settings to Error, Warning or Ignore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but i could  not find any setting for exception handling under Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings

Comment: @AkasnhaGoyal If you're looking for where Eclipse suggests `unreported Exception, xxxException must be caught or thrown...`, I would be very surprised if you can configure this within Eclipse.

Comment: For the same line of code [pInputJson.getString("abc") ] compiler is pointing out the error in some other machine. but its not in mine.

Answer (score 0):

issue is resolved. now compiler is able to point out the unhandled exception. have used latest version of org.Json and working fine !!